# could i able to update input type ="number" in css to change the arrows

Tags: html, css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have tried some css to change the arrow in  but i could not sort it out , why :[output of this :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJwcr.png)

but my screen would be  [my screen output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KiyP7.png) 
or is there any input spinner that can be solved for this actual output [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJwcr.png) any Idea !!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to build your own (for example with span and position or with ::before and ::after) and mask with them the default arrows. But before that you should search here in stackoverflow – there are already many questions like that: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=style+input+number+arrows